# SAP UI5 Transition Parameters

Tags: transition, sapui5

I am using SAP UI5 for a while and thank you all your answers about ui5, it helped me much.

I want to learn what the transition parameters is, i have two views and app. Using `to` function for the navigation between them. But i want slow transition, it happening very fast.

In the `to` function there is `oTransitionParameters` parameter but i don't know how to set it.

Here is the code i'm using to show second view but it is **not slowed the transition** :

> app.to(izinView,"flip",null,"duration:'slow'")

Hope somebody know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the last sentence of the comment for the `sTransitionName` parameter:

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#to

> None of the standard transitions is currently making use of any given
>   transition parameters.

You can also see in the source code for `sap.m.NavContainer` it is not being used:

`/*, oTransitionParameters is unused */`

However, that being said you could monkey patch the the `sap.m.NavContainer.transitions` object with your own custom animation.

```
sap.m.NavContainer.transitions["slowFlip"] = {
    // definition here
};
```

To look at the current implementation of "flip" see here:

https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/NavContainer.js#LC1202